# syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => (SyntaxError) => ruby

Tags: ruby

Good evening.
I develop a program in ruby language and when I put the comma "," I get an error and I couldn't solve it, please help me.

```
require "net/http"
require "colorize"
puts "+================================+".red
puts "|        ABDO[panel-scan]        |".green
puts "+================================+".red
pages = {'admin.php','loginpage.php','index.php','login.php'}
print "Enter url site : "
site = gets.chomp 
for i in pages
    url = URI(site)
    web = Net::HTTP.get_response(url + i)
    puts "[-] #{url}#{i} ".blue + " | ".red + web.code + " | ".red + web.message
    if web.message == 'ok'
        puts "[^_^] admin panel Found ".yellow
    end
end
```

The error is:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => (SyntaxError)
pages = {'admin.php','loginpage.php','index.php','...
                    ^
```

Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wThwp.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpvtl.png)

Comment: It's not Python :) You should use square brackets for array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curly brackets (`{}`) are used in Ruby to define a [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) which is a data structure with keys and values.

In your example, it looks like you want to define an [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) which is a data structure that acts like a list of values. To define an array in Ruby, use square brackets (`[]`) instead, like this:

```
pages = ['admin.php', 'loginpage.php', 'index.php', '...']
```

Comment: I can't use square brackets because it will generate a new error which is:   <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- colorize (LoadError)
 from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
 from c:/Users/Abdullah Abdulkadir/Desktop/course/hack web/scan.rb:2:in `<main>'

Comment: That error is totally unrelated to the first error. It tells you that this line `require "colorize"` is not able to load `colorize`. Did you have the `colorize` gem installed? If that error persists, I suggest opening a new question for it, because it is unrelated to the syntax error from this question.

Comment: Firstly Ruby parser check syntax, then run the script. So you fix syntax, and now some other error